# Prove $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $ n \neq 1 , n + \frac{1}{n} > 2$ using completing the square.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I have got this far; I am only unable to understand how to finish the proof.

$n>0 \implies n + 1/n > 0 \implies n + 1/n + 2 - 2 > 0 \implies {\big(\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\big)}^2 - 2 > 0 \implies {\big(\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\big)}^2 > 2$

How can I use this to prove what's being asked in the question?

Comment: You are mostly there $n + 1/n = n \pm 2 + 1/n \mp 2 = (\sqrt{n} \pm \sqrt{1/n})^2 \mp 2 \ge 0 \mp 2$. So $n + 1/n \ge 2$ with equalition holding if and only if $\sqrt{n} - \sqrt{1/n} = 0$ iff $\sqrt{n} = \sqrt{1/n}$ iff $n = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

$${ \left( \sqrt { n } -\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  }  \right)  }^{ 2 }>0\Rightarrow n-2+\frac { 1 }{ n } >0\Rightarrow n+\frac { 1 }{ n } >2$$

Comment: Thanks. It's incredible how I can complicate such a simple proof.

Comment: @deepdeb. Note that are 2 ways to complete the square. When one option   doesn't seem to work, try the other.

Answer (score 2):

Completing the square a different way:
$$n+\frac1n=\frac{n^2+1}n = \frac{n^2-2n+1+2n}n = \frac{(n-1)^2}n + 2>2$$
The final inequality follows from the assumption that $n$ is not 1, hence the quantity $\frac{(n-1)^2}n$ is strictly positive.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, but without using completing the square:

As $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $n\neq 1$, so $n\geq 2$, and hence $n + 1/n>2$.

Comment: But the question *was* by completing the square.

Comment: Yeah, this is why at the first line I wrote without .... I just thought it may be interesting!

Comment: Thank you! Wow, elegance abounds in these forums. :D